# Discrepancy documentation and implementation of spaCy vectors for German words?

Tags: documentation, spacy, word-embedding

According to [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity):

> spaCy's small models (all packages that end in sm) don't ship with
>   word vectors, and only include context-sensitive tensors. [...]
>   individual tokens won't have any vectors assigned.

But when I use the `de_core_news_sm` model, the tokens Do have entries for `x.vector` and `x.has_vector=True`.

It looks like these are context_vectors, but as far as I understood the documentation only word vectors are accessible through the `vector` attribute and `sm` models should have none. Why does this work for a "small model"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`has_vector` behaves differently than you expect.

This is discussed in the comments on an [issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2523) raised on github. The gist is, since vectors are available, it is `True`, even though those vectors are context vectors. Note that you can still use them, eg to compute similarity.

Quote from spaCy contributor [Ines](https://github.com/ines):

> We've been going back and forth on how the has_vector should behave in
>   cases like this. There is a vector, so having it return False would be
>   misleading. Similarly, if the model doesn't come with a pre-trained
>   vocab, technically all lexemes are OOV.

Version 2.1.0 has been announced to include German word vectors.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Could you also point me in the direction of how the context vectors are computed? Haven't been able to find much about it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about how the vectors are computed. spaCy's documentation on how they create their models for languages other than English is not great, I'm afraid. Since that question is off-topic here, I would suggest you ask either on gitter or reddit: https://gitter.im/explosion/spaCy https://www.reddit.com/r/spacynlp